# What iOS library is used for the Uber traveling status notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, widget

This widget is really cool. Anyone know what library to use to make it?

[image]

Not sure which api this?

Answer (score 0):

This is **Live Activities API in iOS** using Live Activities and ActivityKit.

Live Activities will help you follow an ongoing activity right from your Lock Screen, so you can track the progress of your food delivery or use the Now Playing controls without unlocking your device. — Apple

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities

Here are the tutorials URLS:

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-live-activities-widget-for-ios-16-2c07889f1235
- https://blog.appcircle.io/article/live-activities-in-ios16